# Export Blender Particle System Hair To Three.JS

Tags: three.js, export, blender, mesh, particle-system

After several months of casual research on three.js as I work on a model in Blender 2.7 I have yet to locate a method for exporting the blender particle system hair? By chance would anyone have any ideas how would I go about achieving this feat, would I need to perhaps export to OBJ or some other format? I have yet to see any three.js imported particle systems from any 3d system?..Any ideas would greatly appreciated !!

Answer (score 2):

This solution is a visualized version stated by beiller.

### Step by Step

1. Go to <kbd>Modifiers</kbd>.

   [image]
2. Click <kbd>Convert</kbd>.

   [image]
3. Now the hair become like this.

   [image]
4. Add `Screw` modifier to the hair and so change the `Angle` to `2`.

   [image]
5. Click <kbd>Apply</kbd>.

   [image]
6. Export your model to what file format you need.

Comment: that a very informative set of instructions....I am extremely appreciative...magnificent screenshot!...Great Work!..let me know if I can ever offer you assistance!

Comment: Any idea how to deal with the gltf file size later on?
I used this to make some trees, after converting I ended up with more then a hundred meshes and the file sie was 300MB +

Comment: this does not export animation & simulation

Answer (score 1):

The method I use is make your particle hair. Then, under the modifiers tab, select "convert" to convert it into a mesh.

Next add the "screw" modifier. Set the objects center accordingly to get the best "screw" results. Use X, Y, or Z axis, and change to 2 degrees. Change the number of sections to 2 as well.

This will make a mesh like hair.

Comment: Well that worked great!...Very neat, quick trick any ideas on how to enhance it's appearance for a more realistic look? I did size everything down to appear as a sliver rather then the flat appearance!..Much thanks for you assistance..Great Work!

Comment: Yeah I also scale down the tips. Another method I tired is using the skin modifier which makes a 3d hair strand but required 4x the geometry. You can scale the tips with crtl+a I believe as well. Try solidify on the hair strands made with screw. Thanks!

Comment: Any idea how to deal with the gltf file size later on?
I used this to make some trees, after converting I ended up with more then a hundred meshes and the file sie was 300MB +